# Redux action and async/await functions have different behavior at class component and functional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been working on a Next.js app with these dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
```

One of my redux action that creates the `stepsNameThatMustBeShown` (a property of redux state) is:

```
export const setInitialSteps = () => {
     //.....
     // some codes that creates the stepsNameThatMustBeShown array
     //....
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.SET_QUICK_RESUME_GENERATOR_MODAL_INITIAL_STEPS,
        data: stepsNameThatMustBeShown
    }
};
```

And I used this snippet in two different places in my app, in a class component and a functional component.

```
<button onClick = {
    async () => {
      await this.props.setInitialSteps();
      if (this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown.length > 1) {
        this.props.setCurrentStep(this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown[0]);                                                               
        this.props.setQuickResumeDisplayStatus(true);                                                                    
        this.props.setUnUpdatedStepsName([...this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown]);
      }
    }}>
      Open
</button>
//....
//...


 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        stepsNameThatMustBeShown: state.quickResumeGeneratorModal.stepsNameThatMustBeShown,
    };
};


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
            setQuickResumeDisplayStatus: bindActionCreators(setQuickResumeDisplayStatus, dispatch),
            setInitialSteps: bindActionCreators(setInitialSteps, dispatch),
            setCurrentStep: bindActionCreators(setCurrentStep, dispatch),
            setUnUpdatedStepsName: bindActionCreators(setUnUpdatedStepsName, dispatch),
        }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(resultTest);
```

Obviously, I didn't use `this.props` in a functional component. All those functions in the code snippet are redux actions. In the code snippet, I updated the property of the redux state and I used it right after it updated.
In the class component async and await keywords work as we expected, but in the functional component await keyword doesn't work correctly. I read some related questions that exist in this community but none of them couldn't help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: Based on the code shown above, I dont see any use case of `async await`, you are may be over thinking. Try to remove `async await` and see if that resolves. You are calling this.props.setInitialSteps();` which will run synchronously and return and execute next line in your click handler.

Comment: @Rikin setInitialSteps function initialize the stepsNameThatMustBeShown prop, so I need to initialize it then use it as a part of the condition of if statement, so I should use await function.

Comment: is that function `stepsNameThatMustBeShown` async? if so then use `await` at the call of execution, again no need for await in your click handler.

Comment: It is not a function, it is redux state property.

Comment: `setInitialSteps` is your action creator (based on what you are showing). Its not doing anything other than returning Action with action type and your payload `data`. By you calling it in your functional component only returns that object, you are not doing anything with it. In your Class component you are binding that function with `bindActionCreators` which does `dispatch`ing for you thus it works. Again nothing to do with `async` `await` still based on what you have shown above.

Comment: So what should I do in the functional component that it works as same as the class component?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use react-redux 7.1 or later in order to use `const dispatch = useDispatch()` in your functional component and then call `dispatch()` in your onClick handler.

In your functional component use:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

and then your handler will look like below:

```
<button onClick = {
    async () => {
      const action = this.props.setInitialSteps(); // <======
      dispatch(action); // <=====
      if (this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown.length > 1) {
        this.props.setCurrentStep(this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown[0]);                                                               
        this.props.setQuickResumeDisplayStatus(true);                                                                    
        this.props.setUnUpdatedStepsName([...this.props.stepsNameThatMustBeShown]);
      }
    }}>
      Open
</button>
```

Again all the `async` stuff that you have is not needed here in your use case.